# Wrap an IEnumerable<T> with an ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, ienumerable

From my Repository I get always an `IEnumerable<T>`.

In the Ctor or a method of my ViewModel I want to wrap my entities into an `ObservableCollection<T>` like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> customerViewModels;

public BillingViewModel(IService service)
{
   ...
   IEnumerable<Customer> customers = service.GetCustomers();

   // that will not work because of a different type
   customerViewModels = new ObservableCollection(customers); 

}
```

What would you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have some sort of conversion from Customer to CustomerViewModel:

```
customerViewModels = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>
    (customers.Select(c => ConvertToViewModel(c)));
```

Answer (score 3):

How do you convert a `Customer` to a `CustomerViewModel`? Maybe you just need something like this:

```
customerViewModels = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>(
    from c in customers
    select new CustomerViewModel(c)
);
```